# Update all matching keys in list of dictionaries with value in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

```
key = 'take'
val = 5

dicts = [
    OrderedDict([
        (u'rt', 0), 
        (u'janoameezy', 0), 
        (u'calum', 0), 
        (u'is', 0), 
        (u'me', 0), 
        (u'whenever', 0), 
        (u'i', 0), 
        (u'take', 0), 
        (u'a', 0), 
        (u'selfie', 0), 
        (u'http', 0), 
        (u't', 0), 
        (u'co', 0), 
        (u'sxn68vta2a', 0)
    ]), 
    OrderedDict([
        (u'relax', 0), 
        (u'and', 0), 
        (u'take', 0), 
        (u'notes', 0), 
        (u'while', 0), 
        (u'i', 0), 
        (u'tokes', 0), 
        (u'of', 0), 
        (u'the', 0), 
        (u'marijuana', 0), 
        (u'smoke', 0)
    ])
]
```

How can I replace all instances of key with val?

Comment: Can You post an expected result? Cause I don't know I'm understand it correctly.

Comment: Is there a constraint you haven't mentioned?  Why can't you simply use a loop?

Comment: Do you want in the same order?

Comment: I just want to search this structure in the most efficient way possible. Each OrderedDict has (u'take', 0), which should become (u'take', 5)

Comment: @Fo.: so just loop and set the value.

Comment: Order does not matter? Why use an OrderedDict then?

Comment: I'm using OrderedDict for another purpose used earlier in the script

Comment: @dawg: the OrderedDicts are just a distraction here, I feel. Setting an existing key doesn't change the order, in any case.

Comment: Based on the comments and answer I realize I've just asked the easiest question in the history of SO. Please forgive the Python beginner..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just loop through the list:

```
for od in dicts:
    if key in od:
        od[key] = val
```

The `key in od` tests for membership first; the key will only be updated if it was present before.

Comment: Shouldn't this first test if `key` is in `od`? Otherwise `val` will be added to every dict in the list -- even if not present. The OP said 'match' rather than 'add', no?

Comment: @dawg: in a comment: *Each OrderedDict has (u'take', 0)*

Comment: oh I should clarify - each one in the example above has that key, but in the actual data not all of them will.

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.3 you can use [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) and subclass it to update all its `maps`

```py
>>> from collections import ChainMap

>>> class DeepChainMap(ChainMap):
...     def __setitem__(self, key, value):
...         for mapping in self.maps:
...             if key in mapping:
...                 mapping[key] = value
...         self.maps[0][key] = value

>>> dcm = DeepChainMap(*dicts)
>>> dcm[key] = val  # key = 'take'; val = 5
>>> dicts

dicts = [
    OrderedDict([
        ...
        (u'take', 5),
        ...
    ]),
    OrderedDict([
        ...
        (u'take', 5),
        ...
    ])
]
```